# Java Generic list - using Array.newInstance leads to Nullpointer

Tags: java, list, generics

i'm currently trying to use generic lists to use different datatypes (int,double,string etc.) for one constructor class. I'm running into problems when it's trying to create the array. I'm using following code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class SimpleArrayList<ListedType> extends entrance {
      private int length;
      private int grow;
      private ListedType[] buffer;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SimpleArrayList(int InitialLength,int grow){
        length= 0;
        this.grow = grow;
        buffer = (ListedType[])Array.newInstance(getClass().getComponentType(),InitialLength);
    }
```

using following testing ground:

```
public class entrance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleArrayList<?> A = new SimpleArrayList<Integer>(10,1);

        for (int i=0; i<=A.getLength()-1; i++)
        System.out.print(A.getAt(i)+ ", ");
    }

}
```

can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your call to `getClass().getComponentType()`. The `getClass()` method will return `SimpleArrayList.class`, and then `getComponentType()` will return `null`, because `SimpleArrayList` isn't an array.

Short example of that:

```java
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo<String>().printComponentType();
    }
}

class Foo<T> {
    public void printComponentType() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getComponentType()); // null
    }
}
```

`Array.newInstance` throws a `NullPointerException` if you pass `null` as the first argument.